# Filter Code Coverage results in Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, vstest

I run my tests with `VSTest@2` step with `codeCoverageEnabled: true` (.NET project)

```yaml
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
```

But in the Code Coverage tab, I can see all the **external** dependencies (Managed via NuGet, and Native):

[image: ![enter image description here]

I hid all the names, but the red ones are **external dependencies** and only the green one is my assembly that I want to test. As a result, the total line coverage is way below the actual relevant value...

How can I filter out all the external resources to get the results for my code only?

Comment: I am afraid that you can not directly filter out all the external resources in the Code Coverage.

Comment: It doesn't sound reasonable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research,  if you want to filter out all the external resources, i found a workaround to exclude assemblies manually.You have to add all external resources in your .runsetting file one by one. You can check the steps below.

1.In the .runsettings file,add the following configuration to exclude specific modules (DLLs) from code coverage:

```
<ModulePaths>
  <Exclude>
   <ModulePath>.*XXXX.dll</ModulePath>
   <!-- Add more ModulePath nodes here. -->
  </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022&source=recommendations#include-or-exclude-assemblies-and-members

2 Refer to the .runsettings file using the `runSettingsFile` argument in the VSTest tasK.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    runSettingsFile: '<PATH/TO/FILE.RUNSETTINGS>'
```

Hope it can help you.